# Как встроить шрифт в Java программу?

Tags: java, шрифты

Программа использует swing. На графических элементах используется шрифт, которого может не оказаться у пользователя. Как встроить в программу шрифты, необходимые для работы. Я могу их скопировать в какую-нибудь папку вместе с программой. Но не знаю как их использовать в программе? Подскажите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете положить шрифт в ресурсы проекта, затем загрузить их через InputStream:

```
InputStream is = Class.class.getResourceAsStream("MyFont.ttf");
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
```